# Making toolbar appear when then mouse is hovering it

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".fullscreen-toggle").toggle( 
    function() {
      $("body").addClass("fullscreen");
      $(".fullscreen-toggle").wrap("<div class='fixed-container fixed-toggle' />");
      $(".new_post .wysihtml5-toolbar").wrap("<div class='fixed-container fixed-toolbar' />");
      $(".new_post .form-actions").wrap("<div class='fixed-container fixed-submit' />");
      $(this).children(".toggle-fullscreen").hide();
      $(this).children(".exit-fullscreen").show();
    },
    function() {
      $("body").removeClass("fullscreen");
      $(".new_post .fixed-container").remove();
      $(this).children(".toggle-fullscreen").show();
      $(this).children(".exit-fullscreen").hide();
    }
  );

  // Fade in/out for post fullscreen form
  $('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar').on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).show();
  });
```

**HTML:**

[image]

So, the toolbar should appear when the user places the mouse over the toolbar (I'm using `on` because `.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar` are being added dynamically with jQuery). But when I do so nothing happens.

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried the same in a link and it was triggered. Is there a different way of doing it while hovering a div?

Comment: Is `.fixed-toolbar` hidden? If it is then your script won't work.

Comment: Try making [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it will be easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `on` in the wrong way.

Try it with

```
$(document).on("mouseover", '.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar', function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: You can use `on` like that, anonymous function wise ;)

Comment: `$(selector).on` binds a listener to all elements matched by the selector, that's the same like the classic `bind` variant.
`$(selector).on( event, subselector )` binds a live (!) listener to all elements matchings the `subselector` below the `selector`.

Details information on the jquery site itself: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

I think i got your issue:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".fullscreen .fixed-toolbar", function(){
    $('ul[class$="toolbar"]', this).show();
});
```

Try this and see if helps.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the element which is supposed to receive the `mouseover` event is hidden.

To fix this, you can have a div with transparent contents using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

When your `on()` assignment is evaluated there are no `.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar` elements, so nothing happens. You could try and place it right after the `wrap()`:

```
$(".new_post .wysihtml5-toolbar").wrap("<div class='fixed-container fixed-toolbar' />");
$('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar').on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```